# What is the goal of the Übermensch?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism

I have been reading Thus spoke Zarathustra, and i understand that Man should attempt to act to be like an Overman, or a bridge to one. But i have a dilemma:

Is the Übermensch the final goal of mankind, e.g: the Übermensch is perfect and complete? If so:
What is the goal/purpose of the Übermensch?

or:

Is the Übermensch improvable - e.g: does the Übermensch strive towards his own Übermensch; like an infinite series: Chimp -> Man -> Übermensch1 -> Übermensch2? If so:
Why should i strive to be like the Übermensch or a bridge, to a bridge, to a bridge of one?

If my only reason to strive to act like an Übermensch is for my own improvement and welfare then why should i follow Nietzsche and not other simpler philosophies that do that such as Stoicism?

Many thanks.

Comment: How can a man be more than a man? It's not possible. But a man can try to be better than he is. Your own improvement is not for your benefit, but the benefit of those around you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Uebermensch is not about being better than you are in a moral sense, but about being who you are. His/her task is to understand how she/he has become who he/she is and what she/he can create from her/his own person. For Nietzsche it is important to separate our own self from the influence of others, their opinions and their believes, in order to really become our own person. The freer the Self, the more Uebermensch-like is a person.

Comment: If you have references and especially quotes from Nietzsche they would support your answer and give the reader a place to go for more information. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Nietzsche intened the Übermensch as a goal of every single human being and not as an infinite series process that (by definition) can never be achieved. To become an Übermensch is (in Nietzsche philosophy) an ambition that every woman and man must have, mainly for her/himself but if every human being can go past his moral and his limits there can be an improvement for the all of society.

Answer (score 0):

To be the full self, undeceived and uninhibited.

To go beyond self!

The self is a container, the Übermensch is the full spirit.

There can never be a completely sustained full spirit, rather a capacity which spiritedness fills (and is exhausted) throughout our lives. This is the journey (not a destination) that is our humanity!

Comment: Basically, he was talking about Nonduality, but he didn't describe it very well. Not sure he actually got there.